# Oracle distinct vs java (cqengine/set) : whose leads to better performances?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, set, cqengine

I have a table from which I extract 8 columns, said columns will be properties of a pojo, say MyPojo.

I want to remove duplicates.

I came up with two strategies.

1-Let oracle take care of this with distinct keyword

```
select distinct c1,c2...c8 from TABLE where...`
```

2-Do this in java with cqengine (https://code.google.com/p/cqengine/wiki/DeduplicationStrategies#Logical_Elimination_Strategy):

```
DeduplicationOption deduplication = deduplicate(DeduplicationStrategy.LOGICAL_ELIMINATION);
ResultSet<Car> results = cars.retrieve(query, queryOptions(deduplication));
```

3-Do this in java with a set

```
simply storing rows inside of a Set<MyPojo>
```

From a performance point of view which one is better?

Comment: The one which runs faster on your machine for your dataset.  The best way to find that out is to test it.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to decide these things is to model it.

What are the access patterns in your application?

- If this is would be a one-off request: have the database do the filtering.
- If you expect to get many such identical requests: have the database do the filtering, and consider caching results in the application.
- If you expect to get a variety of queries on the same dataset, consider caching the unfiltered dataset into the application tier, and querying it with CQEngine.

There is no *rule of thumb* such as "always have the database do the work". If your application operates at any kind of scale, you will not want every request to hit the database. You need to scale out your application tier.

On the other hand, you should not over-engineer. The answer depends on the traffic volume and data access patterns that you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Let the database do the work. In this case you don't send unnecessary data over the network which will - probably - have the biggest positive impact on performance.

Also it is the most compact solution in terms of code size.